# Автоматическая запись id в поле БД

Tags: mysql

В БД имеется таблица со столбцами `id` и `followers`.
Имеется 3 пользователя соответственно с `id = 1, 2, 3` и пустыми полями столбца `followers`.
Хочу сделать так, чтобы при добавлении новой строки (со значениями `id 4, 5` и т.д.) к столбцу `followers` пользователю с `id 1` в поле вставлялись эти `id` (в формате `1,2,3,4,5,6,7` и т.д.).
Возможно ли такое реализовать непосредственно в `phpmyadmin`?

Comment: реализовать можно. только phpmyadmin тут не причем. это делается триггерами. И делать этого, в том виде, как вы хотите, не следует ни в коем случае. В БД нельзя хранить значения через запятую. Ну т.е. конечно можно, но потом работать с данными в таком формате дико сложно. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmysql%5D+%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%83%D1%8E

Comment: https://habrahabr.ru/post/254773/ обратите внимание на первую нормальную форму, ваши данные нарушают уже ее. а по хорошему надо стремится что бы БД была 5й нормальной форме, тогда с ней на языке SQL будет легко работать

Comment: Правильнее будет сделать так: убрать из таблицы "Пользователь(User)" колонку с названием "folowers" и добавить таблицу "folower", в которой будет поле idUser(это id пользователя, на которого подписался folower).

Answer (score 0):

Это надо реализовать на уровне кода:

1. При вставке получаем id вставляемой записи.
2. Получаем предыдущие данные (список followers) от пользователя (id 1)
3. Добавляем к ним новый айдишник
4. Далее делаем UPDATE на строке с этим пользователем (id 1)

PHPMyAdmin - это средство управления MySQL, если речь про то, можно ли это реализовать на уровне MySQL, то теоретически можно через триггеры, но получится через одно место. Нормально это все делается через собственный код.